# How to create DB users in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can create users from mongo shell using createUser() function. but i have a requirement that i need to create users from GUI(using nodej,express).Im using mongoose for multiple connections to db. i cant see any functions in mongoose.  is there any functions or packages that supports features like createUser, delete user like this.

Comment: connect using db = mongoose.mongo.MongoClient('mongodb://'+username+':'+password+'@localhost/dbtoconnect, function(err, db){}); using db.admin() function then you can use admin collection and authenticate using admin username and password using admin_db.authenticate('adminusername', 'password'); usign addUser function you can add the users

Answer (score -1, accepted):

connect using 
`db = mongoose.mongo.MongoClient('mongodb://'+username+':'+passwor‌​d+'@localhost/dbtoco‌​nnect, function(err, db){});`

using db object get admin access first. Then you can use admin collection and authenticate using admin username and password using `admin_db.authenticate('adminusername', 'password');` using `addUser` function you can add the users

Comment: Could you explain that better?!

Comment: Pretty old question but I just came across the same thing and found the solution: you have to use [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Db.html#addUser) method. The connection thing is described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/quick-start)